# Socket error: EOF when using ImapLibrary2 with Robot Framework

Tags: testing, automated-tests, robotframework, gmail-imap, imaplib

I'm trying to use ImapLibrary2 for RobotFramework to connect to imap.gmail.com, find a confirmation email and then open the link to validate the account.

```
Open Mailbox   host=imap.gmail.com    username=username@gmail.com   password=password    port=993    is_secure=true
${LATEST}    Wait For Email    sender=noreply@domain.com    timeout=300
${HTML}    Open Link From Email    ${LATEST}
Close Mailbox
```

At the first step, when try to connect to the imap server of gmail I get the following error: abort: socket error: EOF.
The Gmail account have the IMAP access turned on. I'm not able to figure out what the problem could be.
Thanks everyone for the help

Comment: What is the full error and stack trace? 
Where are you running this? At home?  At work?  Has your network administrator blocked it?  Have you tried using another client to see if it works on the same host?  Do you use an app specific password?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.